PHP returns wrong timestamp for DateTimeImmutable object with the time zone set
I want to record a timestamp for a date which has a time zone.
I'd like to use PHP and the DateTimeImmutable object to do it. Unfortunately, It seems to be off by 1 hour, even though I think I set the time zone correctly. Here's my code:
date_default_timezone_set("EDT");
$myDate = new DateTimeImmutable("08/30/2024 4:00 PM",new DateTimeZone("EDT"));
echo $myDate.getTimestamp();

Expected result: 1725048000
Actual result: 1725051600 (I checked a bunch of online converters like https://www.unixtimestamp.com/ and this timestamp is definitely 5:00 PM EDT, not 4:00PM)
This is running on PHP 7.4

error_reporting(E_ALL); (which you should always have on) should give you a clue

Shouldn't that be $myDate->getTimestamp()?

I cannot reproduce. This is not the actual code you're running (because it has a syntax error) so perhaps you have an error somewhere else, most likely due to date_default_timezone_set() not accepting EDT.

@ÁlvaroGonzález some PHP versions (namely 7.4 as OP indicates) produce the value they're getting - https://3v4l.org/jossM. I'd say this is down to discrepancies in the built-in timezone DB

@Phil You're absolutely right, I missed the PHP version part.

The input timezone is not defined. Use "8/30/2024 4:00 PM EDT" and the result is 1725048000.

I'm not sure why it's doing this but my guess would be down to some discrepancy in that particular PHP version's IANA timezone DB.
The incorrect results are the same for all of these EOL versions

5.5.10 - 5.5.38
5.6.0 - 5.6.40
7.0.0 - 7.0.33
7.1.0 - 7.1.33
7.2.0 - 7.2.34
7.3.0 - 7.3.33
7.4.0 - 7.4.33
8.0.0 - 8.0.20
8.1.0 - 8.1.7

You can get the correct result if you drop the globally non-sensical timezone abbreviation and use a real IANA TZ identifier like America/New_York
$myDate = new DateTimeImmutable(
    '08/30/2024 4:00 PM',
    new DateTimeZone('America/New_York')
);

https://3v4l.org/h4V0N
